# HTML5 Audio element flickering on playbackRate change

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

Has anyone resolved flickering in the audio signal when `audio.playbackRate != 1` on Chrome / Windows?

I've read somewhere that this flicker should appear when `rate < 0.5` or `rate > 2.0`. 
But the problem is occurring even when `0.9 < rate < 1.1`.

Here is a sample code with slider between 0.9 and 1.1: http://jsfiddle.net/r6bPF/3/

Comment: I can't seem to find a reported bug for this in the webkit bug tracker (https://bugs.webkit.org). Do you know if it's been reported? Otherwise I'd think it's unlikely that anyone has done anything about it (as in, they might not be aware that it's an issue at all).

Comment: yer, reported, and closed :)
i got this response from Chris from chrome dev team: 

"Actually, I'd expect that - playbackRate on the element isn't very precisely controllable. If you want really precise control, pull the sound in as a buffer and use Web Audio (i.e. a BufferSourceNode) to play it back - a la http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/wubwubwub/index.html "

so, they are aware of this, but there is nothing that they can do about it :)